# Interpreting the Difference in a UML Diagram of Three Classes in a Row versus Sharing a "Line"

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I want to understand the difference between connecting classes together with a shared line or by having classes only "connect" through other classes. Is there a significant difference here? If classes share a line are you specifically trying to convey that information is being accessed from each of the other classes on the shared line?

For "Three Objects in a Row" I mean a layout that would appear as follows (sorry my diagram is:
[image]

For "Sharing Lines" I mean a layout that would appear as follows:

[image: UMl Diagram Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**difference about access**

In the first case instances of *Flat* and instance(s) of *Tenant* know each other, and independently of that instances of *Tenant* and instances of *LeaseAgreement* know each other. Instances of *Flat* do not have direct access to instances of *LeaseAgreement* and instances of *LeaseAgreement* do not have direct access to instances of *Flat*, they can only access the other instances if *Tenant* offers these accesses whatever the way (method or public attribute).

In the second case there is an *association-class*, instances of *Flat* and *Tenant* know each other more the corresponding instance of *LeasingContract* indicating how they are associated.

---

**difference about knowledge**

In the first case supposing the hidden multiplicity are not 1 a tenant having two rents is associated with two instances of *Flat* and two instances of *LeaseAgreement* but there is nothing in the given model allowing to link the right instance of *LeaseAgreement* with the right instance of *Flat*, that means the model as it is do not say for which flat a lease agreement was written.

In the second case there is no ambiguity, each couple of instances *Flat* and *Tenant* is associated with (in fact throw) the right instance of *LeasingContract*

Answer (score 0):

The notation in your lower picture is called Association Class (see [this wiki](https://wiki.c2.com/?AssociationClass)). Bascically it's a shortcut for a `1-* AC *-1` relation where AC is connecting two classes so you can add attributes and operations. In your example the AC is `Leasing contract` and it would add information about duration, payment, etc. And the two `*` were taken from the `*` left and right on the AC's association's far ends. So this would be an equivalent of your lower diagram:

[image]